# PhoenGap app not detecting swipe

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a PhoneGap 2.9 app running on Android 4.4 and it takes several tries to detect a swipe event from jQuery Mobile (v.1.10).  This same code runs beautifully on Android 4.3.
I have tried changing the values for

```
$.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold
$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold
```

but these do not seem to help at all.  Any suggestions?

Below is how I am hooking up the swipe event:

```
$(document).on("swipe", '.collapsed', function (e) {
 // do something
});
```

Comment: What is your targetsdk? if it's 19 you can try to set it to 18 instead, it should force the kitkat webview to operate in compatibility mode

Comment: I'm using swipe event successfully with kitkat, but not on document,  on pagecontent.

Comment: @QuickFix  Thank you.  Just a quick test and it seems setting it to 18 has helped/fixed.  Its def more responsive.  Please add as an answer so i can give you credit.

Comment: It would be better to find a compatible way for the new webview in 4.4, but if you're happy, I'm happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the target SDK to 18 instead of 19 to force the new webview in kitkat to operate in compatibility mode.

Comment: I have an app using target SDK 17 but the problems persist. Have you another suggestion?

Comment: @Carlos487, try to use the swipe on the pagecontent instead of the document.

Comment: I'm binding the events into a <div> tag that has an image slider with $(document).on() is that ok?