# Swipe not detected on Android 4.4 in jquery mobile Cordova project

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having the same problem as described in the following thread:

[PhoenGap app not detecting swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048007/phoengap-app-not-detecting-swipe/22048527#22048527)

Unfortunately, changing my target sdk to "18" (instead of Kitkat "19") in my /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml isn't having any effect.  I do notice that my project.properties file still lists my target as 19, and says do not change this file.

## This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.

## Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!

Is this overriding my xml manifest file?  Have I missed something?  Is there another way to fix this swipe detection problem?  As of now my app detects maybe one out of every 5 or 6 swipes.  Completely unusable.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Incidentally, I did try modifying that file and discovered that my build failed (due to missing Android SDK 18).  So that's good news.  I installed SDK 18 and fired up the build.  Success. Bad news: It didn't fix my problem.  Still having serious swipe issues on Kitkat.  Swipe works fine on my old Droid Razr MAXX (Jelly Bean?).

Comment: did anyone manage to get this working?

Comment: use the android native code to detect swipe actions, and then use `webview.loadUrl("var event=document.createEvent('Event');event.init('swipe-left-a');document.dispatchEvent(event);"); `when detected swipe-left action, on the client side: use `document.addEventListener('swipe-left-a', function(e){//...});`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've since thrown JQuery Mobile on the ground, using Ionic framework instead, swiping works great over there...